# Adding listener to hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I recently came across a situation where I have to do some actions when object is updated through **Hibernate session**, but hibernate session does not have any methods where I can add update listener. To summarize my intent I am posting a sample program.

```
public class SessionListenerTest{

    public static void main(String[] args){

            ...     

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.addSessionListener(new SessionListener(){

            onUpdate(Object dbObject){
                ...
            }

            onDelete(Object dbObject){
                ...
            }

            onInsert(Object dbObject){
                ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Whenever ant object is updated through hibernate session, **onUpdate** should be called and so on. But Hibernate session does not have any methods similar to **addSessionListener**. Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a generic DAO, and make use of some kind of interceptor.

Resources:

- [Interceptors and Events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html), Hibernate reference
- [Interceptor in Hibernate](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/9-interceptors-in-hibernate-orm-framework-an-introducti-1.html), javabeat.net
- [Hibernate Interceptor Example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/), mykong.com
- [Don't repeat the DAO (Generic DAO)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao.html), developerworks, IBM

Comment: Thanks for response, can u explain in detail or is there any related link.

Comment: @hnm: Updated my post to include some resources.